# Enforce IPv4 for certain hosts

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, routing

How can I enforce IPv4 to be used when accessing certain hosts?

Can this be done, ideally specifying by domain names?

What I tried, but am not sure if I'm going to be able to do this, is - create a new interface and route the specific hosts via this interface only, and then disable IPv6 for it entirely.

Does this sound any good? Can this be done in a better approach?

Comment: *"create a new interface and route the specific hosts via this interface only, and then disable IPv6 for it entirely"* - to be honest I don't see any other way.

Answer (score 3):

Routing only happens after the hostname has been resolved into an IP address. To enforce IPv4-only, you would ideally manipulate the hostname resolution to only return IPv4 addresses for those "certain hosts".

If you can manipulate a DNS server, you could perhaps configure it to return only IPv4 addresses for those hosts.

If you can only manipulate the client end, you could provide IPv4 addresses (only) for the hosts in question in `/etc/hosts`, and ensure that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has `files` before `dns` and/or `resolve`.

If the hostname resolution returns multiple IP addresses (and the application in question is IPv6-ready, so it uses `getaddrinfo()` instead of the old `gethostbyname()`), then `/etc/gai.conf` determines the order in which the addresses are tried. If the "certain hosts" are in a specific IPv4 network (or a small number of individual IP addresses), then you could add a precedence rule in `gai.conf` to prefer IPv4 for them. But this just sets a precedence order: it will not be able to stop the application from falling back to IPv6 if an IPv4 connection attempt fails.

If the IPv6 addresses of the "certain hosts" are known and static, you could set up `iptables` or `nftables` firewall rules to `REJECT` (not `DROP`!) any IPv6 connection attempts to those hosts. On the client end, that would mean setting up OUTPUT firewall rules, e.g.

```
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <ipv6-address-of-certain-host> -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d <ipv6-address-of-certain-host> -j REJECT
```

Note that by default the `REJECT` target creates an ICMP(v6) "port unreachable" response. Using `--reject-with tcp-reset` on TCP connections might help to ensure that any applications trying an IPv6 connection to that port will quickly fall back to any alternative addresses they may have resolved, i.e. to IPv4.

(If you are enforcing this restriction at the server end, using `--reject-with tcp-reset` on rejecting IPv6 TCP connections may be even more important, as overy paranoid firewalls between the client and the server might drop the ICMP.)